# How can I use CSS to make a multi-select box but have the label appear on top instead of to the left?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3.2.8 application and I'm trying to customize some of the classes that come with the simple_form_for gem.

I have a page with many multiple select boxes on it, and to use space wisely I want the labels to appear on top of the select boxes.

I can't quite figure out how to do that. I have very little CSS experience and I'm trying to dive right in. I have used `float` with some success, but when you use simple_form_for you end up with a bunch of nested `<div>` tag for a form element. So my select box is only floating as far left as the containing `<div>` tag. I want it to be in line with the label. Here is a rendered example:

```
<div id="attribute_value_list" class="attribute_value_list">
  <div class="control-group select required">
    <label class="select required control-label" for="app_attribute1">
      <abbr title="required">*</abbr>
      Vehicle: Make
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select id="app_attribute1" class="select required select_attribute_value" size="10" name="app[attribute1]">
        ...
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm on mobile so I won't get into detail. But look into absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to apply position:relative to the containing div (pick one that holds the label and the controls), and then position:absolute to the label, along with left and top to position it wherever you want - relative to the containing div.